# How to create MBTile file from local XYZ tile directory using gdal_translate

Tags: gdal-translate, mbtiles

I have a local XYZ tile cache in directories from zoom level 0 to 14 of a curtain area.
I would like to build a .mbtiles file from the png's in these directories to serve as a layer from geoserver.

How can I use gdal_translate to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know if that will answer your question, but I explained how to create MBTile file from local XYZ tile directory here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/429228/151246