# Generating high resolution MBTiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, resolution, mbtiles, xyz-tiles

Is it option to generate MBTiles file in **high resolution (512x512 / 192DPI)** in QGIS?

**Generate XYZ tiles (Directory)** tool allows to create high resolution tiles, but in **Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)** tool there are no tile width and height parameters so I cannot create 512x512 tiles.

If no, is it any other way to generate it from XYZ Directory tiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

1. I used **Generate XYZ tiles (Directory)** to generate 512x512, 192DPI tiles
2. I added metadata.json file to generated directory
3. I used **[mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil)** library to generate .mbtiles file

   python mb-util PATH_TO_DIRECTORY FILENAME.mbtiles --image_format=FORMAT

and I get a high-resolution MBTiles file.

Answer (score 3):

The Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles) tool really does not have an option for setting the tile size. Use gdal_translate and MBTiles outputformat instead. The MBTiles raster driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html has the desired option:

> Raster only:
>
> BLOCKSIZE=integer. (GDAL >= 2.3) Block/tile size in width and height
> in pixels. Defaults to 256. Maximum supported is 4096.

Comment: And how to use gdal_translate with tile directory as an input? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408141/how-to-create-mbtile-file-from-local-xyz-tile-directory-using-gdal-translate

Comment: With a TMS minidriver https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219035/open-local-tms-in-qgis-using-gdal/219039

Comment: Is it any place with example of gdal_translate and TMS as an input, because it's extremely hard to find one?