# Generating MBTiles from TIFF with the same quality in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, tiles, resolution, mbtiles

I tried several methods with QGIS 3.28 to generate a *.mbtiles* from a georeferenced *.tif*, but other methods failed except the ["Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#generate-xyz-tiles-mbtiles) tool but the output *.mbtiles* getting a low quality compared to the *.tif*.

The plugin that I tried and failed to generate (for my situation):

1. `QTiles` (generate blank coordinates although the CRS is set) - Failed
2. `QMetaTiles` (generate blank coordinates) - Failed
3. [Generating high resolution MBTiles in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429088/generating-high-resolution-mbtiles-in-qgis) (I refer to this but get the same resolution as below)

My setting in `Raster Tool > Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)`:

[image]

Does my setting set wrong to produce at least some resolution like the *.tif* file? Any idea?

Comment: What is the quality of your *tif*? Did you try the [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#gdal-translate) instead ?

Comment: Using same tool, my tif was generated poorly. Also the nodata were mapped back and shown in the mbtile.