# Unable to set zoom level when convert tif to mbtiles using gdal_translate in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, tiles, gdal-translate, mbtiles

Continue from this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445074/generating-mbtiles-from-tiff-with-the-same-quality-in-qgis?noredirect=1#comment726514_445074), for my situation, the only way to generate *.tif* to *.mbtiles* is
`gdal_translate` in QGIS.

This is the *.json* after using `gdal_translate`

Setting: `GDAL > Raster conversion > translate(convert format)`

```json
{
  "tiles": [
    "http://localhost:8009/data/openmaptiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  ],
  "name": "something8",
  "format": "png",
  "basename": "something8.mbtiles",
  "id": "something8",
  "type": "overlay",
  "description": "something8",
  "version": "1.1",
  "bounds": [
    101.03159452420243,
    3.9388754188813304,
    101.04662092965613,
    3.9534099669676817
  ],
  "minzoom": 21,
  "maxzoom": 21,
  "center": [
    101.03910772692927,
    3.9461426929245063,
    21
  ],
  "tilejson": "2.0.0"
}
```

And this is the what I need:

```json
{
  "tiles": [
    "http://localhost:8009/data/openmaptiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  ],
  "name": "something",
  "format": "png",
  "basename": "something.mbtiles",
  "id": "something",
  "type": "overlay",
  "description": "something",
  "version": "1.1",
  "minzoom": 8,
  "maxzoom": 25,
  "bounds": [
    101.02890014648438,
    3.936870437606864,
    101.05138778686523,
    3.9575921925703916
  ],
  "center": [
    101.0401439666748,
    3.9472313150886276,
    16
  ],
  "tilejson": "2.0.0"
}
```

As you can see the above *.json* `minzoom` and `maxzoom` is fixed at **21**, and the below are **8-25**. How to set the zoom level from **14-20**?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By the documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html the driver allows only small adjustment to the base zoom level

> ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=AUTO/LOWER/UPPER. Strategy to determine zoom
> level. LOWER will select the zoom level immediately below the
> theoretical computed non-integral zoom level, leading to subsampling.
> On the contrary, UPPER will select the immediately above zoom level,
> leading to oversampling. Defaults to AUTO which selects the closest
> zoom level.

Oversampling more that to UPPER is unreasonable, it would just split pixels and explode the disk space.

How to add lower zoom levels is documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html#overviews-raster

> Overviews (raster)
>
> gdaladdo / BuildOverviews() can be used to compute overviews. Only
> power-of-two overview factors (2,4,8,16,…) are supported.
>
> If more overview levels are specified than available, the extra ones
> are silently ignored.

So, for adding zoom levels 14-20 use gdaladdo and see if it is willing to create all the zoom levels that you ask.

```
gdaladdo my_mbtiles.mbtiles 2 4 8 16 32 64 128
```

Answer (score 0):

`gdal_translate` allows setting the target raster resolution in georeferenced units per pixel using the [`-tr`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-tr) option. That can effectively set `maxzoom`. For example, if the georeferenced units are meters and the desired maximum resolution is 1.0 meters per pixel, one can use e.g.:

```
gdal_translate -tr 1.0 1.0 -projwin 480000 6600000 481000 6599000 -projwin_srs EPSG:3857 -co TILE_FORMAT=PNG -co TYPE=baselayer -of MBTILES frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml my_tiles.mbtiles
```

to download a piece of OpenStreetMap to mbtiles. The source dataset XML configuration file is [frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/wms/frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml):

```
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="TMS">
        <ServerUrl>https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>19</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <!--
    <UserAgent>Please add a specific user agent text, to avoid the default one being used, and potentially blocked by OSM servers in case a too big usage of it would be seen</UserAgent>
    -->
    <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

When reading TMS (XYZ tile) maps, the `<TileLevel>19</TileLevel>` setting also sets the maximum allowed zoom level directly for the source dataset and can be used instead of the `-tr` option. See https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html#tms for the relevant documentation.

As @user30184 answered, to set the `minzoom` limit, one needs to add lower zoom levels (overview images) to the produced mbtiles file using [gdaladdo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html). Assuming your `maxzoom` is 20, add six lower zoom levels (14-19) using:

```
gdaladdo my_mbtiles.mbtiles 2 4 8 16 32 64
```